# interop protect memory validation

Tags: c#, c, interop

I have a DLL written in C, which I must use.
It is ok, but in one place I get an error.

```
int getHourTime() 
{
   struct tm *psttm;

   time_t timet = //is initialzed correctly

   psttm = localtime(&timet);

   int nHour = psttm->tm_hour;

   return nHour;
}
```

I am calling it in C# using DLLImport.
When getting to line: "psttm->tm_hour" I get an error (throw) that "Attempted to read or write to protected memory". I understand that it is because it returns a pointer to an inner place of struct tm, but how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: why not post the code for "is initialised correctly"?

Comment: Because the problem is not from there it is from the fact that localtime returns a pointer to a inner memory.

Comment: @Roman There is no such thing as "inner memory" and that is not the problem.

Comment: You critically depend on proper CRT initialization.  Fwiw, it makes little sense to me to not use DateTime.Now.Hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems was because the next line :

struct tm *psttm;

It was not initialize to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what is going on in this case since [`localtime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc(VS.71).aspx) returns a pointer to statically allocated memory. Very Bad Things(tm) must be afoot for `localtime` to return a bad pointer. Now, if your `timet` struct has bad values, MSDN states a `NULL` value will be returned.

I think there is memory which has been trashed in your application.

Does the following work:

```
int getHourTime()
{
    struct tm *psttm = NULL;
    time_t timet;

    time(&timet);
    psttm = localtime(&timet);

    int nHour = psttm->tm_hour;
    return nHour;
}
```

Comment: Maybe "//is initialzed coorectly" is not as "coorect" as we are led to believe...

Comment: No, I checked this with NULL and it behaves the same.

Comment: What is `errno` after the call to `localtime`? If `errno` is zero, then the program is trashing private memory somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
int getHourTime() 
{
   struct tm *psttm;

   time_t timet = //is initialzed coorectly

   // what is psstm?  Set a breakpoint on this line and look at it
   // before and after executing localtime()
   psttm = localtime(&timet);

   // if it's non-null then you can also do this:
#if _DEBUG
   if (!HeapValidate(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, psttm)) {
       puts("bad ptr in getHourTime");
   }
#endif
   int nHour = psttm->tm_hour;

   return nHour;
}
```

Comment: It appears the time buffer used by `localtime` is allocated on a per thread basis using `_malloc_crt`. Is `HeapValidate` the correct one to use to make sure it isn't trashed?

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

```
time_t StartTime = time(NULL);
struct tm * StartLocalTime = localtime(&StartTime);
int hour = StartLocalTime->tm_hour;
```

If this doesnt work, its likely you have some buffer overrun somewhere else in your code, and its just manifesting itself inside this function.